# No resource identifier found for attribute 'indeterminateTintMode' in package Android

Tags: android, xamarin

I am getting an error in my android application developed in Xamarin 5.10.2. I am trying to run MapsAndLocationDemo_v3 but it fails to build the application successfully.
Please help me to solve this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <ProgressBar  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_progress"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateTint="#4184F3"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_atop"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `android:indeterminateTint` your **minimum** api must be Api 21. What I do to change the color of my ProgressBar is using `SetColorFilter()`, like this:

```
var color = Color.ParseColor("#4184F3");
var progressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.place_autocomplete_progress);
progressBar.IndeterminateDrawable.SetColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
```